# Change ubercart default path

Tags: 7, routes, ubercart

My clients really really insist that the path of the cart pages will be store/* instead of cart/*

Also, an alias is not good enough. They want a totally unrelated page to appear in the path: cart

Crazy? yes. Challenging? you bet.

Comment: This will be a fair amount of work. You can change the paths with a simple menu alter, but that won't change any of the internal links Ubercart uses to get to those pages. For example, `grep -nr cart/checkout ubercart` will show you a bunch of forms and page callbacks that need to be overridden for the checkout page, just to make sure the checkout process doesn't break completely. Same thing goes for all the other cart/* pages. Not to mention any ubercart contrib modules you have installed that might rely on those paths

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite all needed paths by [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). It is invoked  by `menu_router_build()`.

Comment: It's really not that simple...

Comment: :) So I do not know another way. If you look here http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.module/function/uc_cart_menu/7 It is fixed by code. So you can alter it by another code using hook_men_alter. I do not know If a such module exists.